# Recursively building a data class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, recursion

I have am trying to create a recursive data class like so:

```
data class AttributeId (
  val name: String,
  val id: Int,
  val children: List<AttributeId>?
)
```

The thing I'm struggling with now is building the data class by iterating over a source object.
How do I recursively build this object?? Is a data class the wrong solution here?

EDIT: Some more information about the Source object from which I want to construct my data class instance

The source object is a Java Stream that essentially* has the following shape:

```
public Category(final String value,
                      final Integer id,
                      final List<Category> children) {
    this.value = value;
    this.id = id;
    this.children = children;
}
```

(For brevity the fields I don't care about have been removed from example)

I *think* I need to map over this stream and call a recursive function in order to construct the AttributeId data class, but my attempts seem to end in a stack overflow and a lot of confusion!

Comment: Depends what the source object looks like.

Comment: Your final data class looks nice - is immutable. If this constraint does not suit your needs when creating the instance then consider using builder pattern. You can introduce some Builder where the data structures are all mutable, but in the end you transform everything in this immutable structure and return it to the outer world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything *necessarily* wrong with a data class that contains references to others.

There are certainly some gotchas.  For example:

- If the list were mutable, or if its field was mutable (i.e. `var` rather than `val`), then you'd have to take care because its hashcode &c could change.
- And if the chain of links could form a loop (i.e. you could follow the links and end up back at the original class), that could be very dangerous.  (E.g. calling a method such as `toString()` or `hashCode()` might either get stuck in an endless loop or crash the thread with a `StackOverflowError`.  You'd have to prevent that by overriding those methods to prevent them recursing.)  But that couldn't happen if the list and field were both immutable.

None of these issues are specific to data classes, though; a normal class could suffer the same issues (especially if you overrode methods like `toString()` or `hashCode()` without taking care).  So whether you make this a data class comes down to whether it *feels* like one: whether its primary purpose is to hold data, and/or whether the automatically-generated methods match how you want it to behave.

As Tenfour04 says, it depends what you're constructing these *from*.  If it naturally forms a tree structure, then this could be a good representation for it.

Obviously, you wouldn't be able to construct a parent before any of its children.  (In particular, the first instance you create would have to have either `null` or an empty list for its `children`.)  This would probably mean traversing the source in post-order.  The rest should fall out naturally from that.